# CQL to XML with string substitution using geotools?

Tags: java, geotools, cql-filter

I have some cql `attr > PLACEHOLDER` that I want to convert to valid XML using geotools. I have heard of terms like filter functions that can somehow replace the placeholder with a function, but not totally sure the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/geotools/code/ogc/2015/03/18/Generating-OGC-Filters.html) about this a few years ago.

```
    org.geotools.xml.Configuration configuration = new org.geotools.filter.v1_0.OGCConfiguration();
    org.geotools.xml.Encoder encoder = new org.geotools.xml.Encoder(
        configuration);
    encoder.setIndenting(true);

    line = "attr > PLACEHOLDER";
    try {
        Filter filter = CQL.toFilter(line);
        // System.out.println("\t" + filter);
        encoder.encode(filter, org.geotools.filter.v1_0.OGC.Filter, System.out);
    } catch (CQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Obviously, in a real program, you'd want to write to a StringBuffer or something instead of stdout. If you want to use the filter at other points in the GeoTools code all you need is `filter`.

Comment: Thanks for this writeup, pretty cool stuff. Is there a possible implementation you know of regarding functions? I know this is valid in the 2.0 spec

Comment: Just change the configuration to version 2.0

Comment: Ideally what I'm wanting is when a function tag is hit in the XML when I'm converting from XML to CQL it will replace all the placeholders with my input parameters.